# Help with the formula

Tags: probability

The following is motivated by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478184/how-do-i-calculate-dice-probability).

I understand that there is an answer to this question on this website but due to having ADD I am finding it extremely difficult to follow the answer I would like to have a confirmation on the formula of calculating probability by having someone tell me if the formula below is correct or not.

$$(A - B) / A = C$$

And if the above formula is correct how would I find the probability of $5^6/6^6$ while using the above formula

Legend:

A = Number of outcomes,

B = Number of negative outcomes,

C = Answer.

Comment: The below questions answer should be 46656 - 15625 = 31031 (46656 - 31031)/46656

Comment: Which question/answer do you mean ?

Comment: Problems like this generally cannot be answered unless you ask the entire question. You wrote only a few bits and pieces of something. Please try to find some way to edit your question so that it says what the exact problem is that is to be solved. Even a link to the other question would help.

Comment: Sorry for being confusing, the question I want answered is if my formula is correct, my formula is A minus B over A. The second question I asked was how it applied in the situation of 5 to the power of 6 over 6 to the power of 6

Comment: Is the formula correct for *what*? What probability are you trying to compute?

Comment: The formula would in the case of that question by put like this 6-5=1, 1 is the negative outcome here so it should then be 6'6 - 1'6/6'6 but this doesn't work so I instead used the answers to each of the given points which would be 46656 (6'6) - 15625 (5'6) = 31031 (1'6) and then put those into the formula making it (46656 - 31031)/46656 = 5'6/6'6.

Comment: I am asking if this formula will give me a percentage under 100% or under 1.0 that will be the correct answer to anything substituted with the legend

Comment: No.  Let A = 5,678,386 = # of people in Quirkberg.  Let B = 4,345,786 = the number of people in Quirkberg who do not own elephants.  So C = A - B/A  = 5678385.2346793613537367836564827 which is the answer to .... what?  Certain *not* the probability of someone in Quirkberg owning an elephant....

Comment: The answer should be 1332600/5678386 = 0.2346793614

Comment: Im sorry if you misunderstood how to apply the formula I've put forward but ill try and word it again.

Comment: You wrote: "I am finding it extremely difficult to follow the answer". Would you **please** post a link to that answer so we have some clue what you are writing about.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478184/how-do-i-calculate-dice-probability

Comment: Number of outcomes minus Number of negative outcomes = Number of positive outcomes, Number of positive outcome over Number of outcomes = Answer or it could be put as A - B = C, C/A=D or (A-B)/A=D

Comment: In finding the answer for 5'6/6'6 I went 6'6 - 5'6 = 1'6 then I went (6'6 -1'6)/ 6'6 = 5'6/6'6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have directed our attention to the question
[How do i calculate Dice probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478184/how-do-i-calculate-dice-probability),
there are a few different parts to that question.
But the answer that you are trying to work with appears to be
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/478192,
which answers a very particular question:

> Suppose I roll six fair six-sided dice. What is the probability that at least one of the dice will come up "$6$" when I roll them?

Assuming we can identify the dice 
(the first die, the second die, and so forth),
there are $6^6$ possible outcomes we can distinguish, each outcome a
unique list of the numbers that appear on each die after rolling.
Since we said the dice were fair, each of these outcomes is equally likely.

If we consider rolling one or more $6$s to be a "favorable" outcome
and any other outcome is "not favorable",
there are $5^6$ "not favorable" (or "negative") outcomes
(the number of ways to have numbers $1,2,3,4,$ or $5$ on each of
$6$ dice).

That leaves $6^6 - 5^6$ "favorable" outcomes.

So if $A=6^6$, $B=5^6$, and $C$ is the probability of rolling at least
one $6$ on the six dice, then you have the correct formula:
$$
(A - B)/A = C.
$$
Plugging in the numeric values:
$$
(6^6 - 5^6)/6^6 = (46656 - 15625) / 46656 = 31031/ 46656 
\approx 0.665102
$$

Some people would prefer to write this formula like this:
$$ C = \frac{A-B}{A}.$$
One can also use the fact
$$
 \frac{A-B}{A} = 1 - \frac BA,
$$
that is, another version of this formula is
$$
C = 1 - \frac BA.
$$

Notice that
$$ \frac{6^6 - 5^6}{6^6} = 1 - \frac{5^6}{6^6}.$$

Again, $(6^6 - 5^6)/6^6$ is the probability you roll at least one $6$
when you roll six dice; 
$5^6/6^6$ is the probability that you do not roll *even one $6$*
when you roll six dice.

So you have some formulas that are correct answers to some questions.
On the other hand, you have tried to use some incorrect formulas.
The difference $6^6 - 5^6$ is not equal to $1^6$,
and $(6^6 -1^6)/ 6^6$ is not equal to $5^6/6^6.$

Comment: Thank you for confirming the formula and for correcting the mistake as 1'6 = just 1 and not 31031.